# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference ViewBag.Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Why I got this error with ViewBag.Message

"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

This is the controller code :

```
 public ActionResult Edit(List<RESULT> list)
        {
           
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (db_a85fa6_globalqualityEntities db = new db_a85fa6_globalqualityEntities())
                {
                    foreach (var i in list)
                    {
                        var c = db.RESULTS.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(i.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (c != null)
                        {
                            c.RESULT1 = i.RESULT1;
                        }
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //return RedirectToAction("Details");

                }
                ViewBag.Message("Updated Successfully");
                return View(list);
                
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message("Failed ! Please try again");
                return View(list);
            }
          

        }
```

This is view code :

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" style="margin:100px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger" />
               </div>
        </div>

    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <p style="color:green;font-size:16px;">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </p>
    }
```

when click SAVE button its not show the message and show the error
on this line of code :

```
 ViewBag.Message("Updated Successfully");
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: Use `ViewBag.Message = "Updated Successfully";`. ViewBag is a form of dynamic View Data Dictionary, your code is trying to invoke function which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code it looks like you are not using razor syntax with the if block. Try using razor syntax and check if it causing the same issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: How to use razor syntax ? can you write the example

Comment: @if (ViewBag.Message != null)

Comment: when I added @ before if in view it shows error now "Unexpected if keyword after @ character once inside code you do not need to prefix constructs like if with @"

Comment: I created a new application to check it but it seems to be working fine. the view code is                                                                                                                                              
           @if (ViewBag.Message == "Hello")
    {
         <h1 class="display-4">@ViewBag.Message</h1>   
    }

Comment: can you post the controller code and view code please I will compare it with my code

Comment: public IActionResult Index()
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            if (a == b)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Hello";

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Bye";
            }
            return View();
        }                                                                                                                                          Here is the controller code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).